# Do I need add "feel" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> Outdoor activities didn't make him happy, but (feel) sleepy.

Do I need to write *feel* there? Why or why not?

Comment: An *idea!* Outdoor activities make him feel sleepy, and not happy!

Comment: "Outdoor activities didn't make him (feel) happy, just sleepy".  In this sentence, "feel" is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be not only unnecessary but wrong to write "feel" before "sleepy" for two reasons:

- lack of parallelism. Since "make" can be followed by an object and an adjectival object complement, if we find an adjective first, there's no reason (and it would be wrong) to write an infinitive to introduce the second object complement. The correct pattern would then be: *not make sb (adjective) but (adjective)*, and NOT *not make sb (adjective) but feel (adjective)*
- if a verb that is shared by both adjectives is used, it should come first (as Andrew proposed): *not make sb feel (adjective) but (feel (adjective))*. Since the same infinitive it used, it can and should be omitted before the second adjective.

If different verbs are required, then both will have to be used. Notice the parallel use of two infinitives: *Outdoor activities didn't make him **feel** happy but **fall** asleep.*